# Should I avoid descending leaps of a minor 6th in species counterpoint?

Tags: species-counterpoint

[image]A little background:
I am teaching myself species counterpoint by reading multiple texts and doing exercises. My primary text is Salzer and Schacter’s “Counterpoint in Composition,” which I really like. I’ve also found of lot of great online resources like “Open Music Theory” and “Sound Patterns.” I’ve been checking my counterpoint exercises using Are Nova’s excellent “Counterpointer” program, which identifies potential errors such as parallel 5ths.

My question:
In designing a counterpoint melody, all texts allow ascending and descending leaps of 3rds, 4ths, 5ths and Octaves. Things get a little fuzzier with 6ths. All sources prohibit ascending and descending major 6ths.

My confusion is about leaps of a minor 6th.

Most sources (when they discuss this at all), allow for ascending leaps of minor 6ths but not descending leaps of a minor 6th. Salzer shows descending leaps of a minor 6th in some of his examples but never discusses the issue.

Should I avoid descending leaps of a minor 6th? Why?

Comment: Not allowed in species counterpoint. Common in Bach chorales though.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't understand why Salzer would have descended to A in the soprano there.  I Jeppesen's book (cited in an answer below) he suggests avoiding rising by a major third to the raised leading tone.  Further, descending by a minor third here to D to my ears a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Generally descending minor sixths are forbidden, at least according to Zarlino and Jeppesen.

"As already mentioned, all perfect, major, and minor intervals up to the fifths are permitted in ascending as well as in descending motion, as is the perfect octave, whereas the minor sixth is allowed ascending only." (Jeppesen in *Counterpoint:
The Polyphonic Vocal Style of the Sixteenth Century*, Chapter III on First Species).

Comment: yes, but the question was ‘why’ and it’s a good question. Fux himself seems to have inherited this rule unquestioned and vaguely talks about larger intervals such as major sixths, all augmented intervals and all sevenths as being difficult to sing and ‘unpleasant’. But why the minor sixth ascending only is ok I can’t fully understand. Given that leaps need to be approached and departed on contrary motion it’s possible that the movement (in c mixolydian) e-f a-b never arose because of the stressed tritone.

Comment: f-g b-c has the f tendency note ascending and leap to a leading note: both less than ideal. But why b-c e-f might fall foul I can’t think.

Comment: of course e-f a-b stresses a diminished fifth, not a tritone so there goes that idea as well... b-c e-f  *does* outline a tritone but I’m still guessing really.

Comment: Thanks all for your thoughtful comments! Is it possible that Salzer's relative permissiveness about the descending m6 has to do with his stated goal to connect Fux' work with baroque and romantic harmonic conventions? Jeppesen, on the other hand, seems more focused on documenting the style of the 16th century.

Comment: I've added an image of Salzer's example above. The descending m6 occurs in bar 6. Damian--you'll notice that Salzer departs from the leap with another small leap instead of a step, which seems to open up many more possibilities in this situation.

Comment: The "why" bit was added in the edit so I didn't address it in my original answer. Honestly, though, most of these "rules" were derived from existing works after the fact. I'm guessing the why has to do with ease of singing, since most of these works were written for amateurs in church choirs. Through the Middle Ages, the third, and therefore sixth, was considered dissonant so maybe it's a hold over from that, too.

Comment: Steve, yes, Schachter and others ignore the ‘rule’ (as i do) when looking at contrapuntal backgrounds in Baroque and later musics. Still genuinely curious about the historical origins of this seemingly not-necessary prohibition.

Comment: @JacobSundstrom: A minor point, but just to note, there were essentially no "amateurs" in "church choirs" in the renaissance that sang polyphony.  Polyphony only tended to be sung in major cathedrals or private aristocratic chapels with a patron who could pay to support professional singers.  The only thing "amateur" church singers did in the renaissance was sing plainchant, and the vast majority of them likely couldn't read music notation (only knowing the Guidonian hand for learning). The rules about sixths may be related to ease of singing, but not because of "amateur" singers.

Comment: @Athanasius I stand corrected!